# Can't run ruby application successfully on ubuntu subsystem(wsl) on windows?

Tags: ruby, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed `Ubuntu(WSL)` on `Windows` to run the `ruby` application on that `Ubuntu`.

I just clone a repo in `Ubuntu(WSL)` and just hit `bundle install` so it is giving this error every time

`-bash: /mnt/c/Ruby27-x64/bin/bundle: C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

what's wrong here?

Comment: It seems your Ruby installation is not found. What version of Ruby did you install on the Ubuntu WSL environment? What is the result of running `ruby -v` in your terminal? And does running `irb` (_Interactive Ruby_) from your terminal work?

Comment: i have installed `ruby 2.7.5p203` and yes `irb` is working

Comment: WSL and Windows are (mostly) separate. Thus, you can't use your Ruby installation you have in your Windows environment within the Ubuntu environment. Instead, you have to install a separate Ruby within your Ubuntu environment.

Comment: @HolgerJust I have already installed separate ruby within `Ubuntu WSL` environment

Comment: @FahadSubzwari Could be that your `bundle` command points to a no-longer-existing Ruby. You could try deinstalling _bundler_ and installing again? (`gem uninstall bundler` / `gem install bundler`)